# Simple Silverlight Examples

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have just started learning silverlight. Whenever I start learning something new I find it very useful to go through a lot of simple applications to see how other people are doing things. Could anoyone point me a collection of fairly simple silverlight examples? preferably version 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right here: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/handsonlabs/

Good luck!